# PDO: Pasar LAST_INSERT_ID de un método INSERT a otro método SELECT

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Mi intención es la de realizar al mismo tiempo la inserción de un registro y obtener el id (AUTO_INCREMENT) del mismo para usarlo como FK para insertar en otra tabla varios registros que la usarán. Primero quiero realizar una select, para más tarde crear un tercer método con el segundo insert, pero necesito saber cómo pasar esa ID de un método al otro.

```
//**
// INSERT 

public function inserT(){       
    $conexion = new Conexion();
    $consulta = $conexion->prepare('INSERT INTO '.self::TABLA.' (tienda_nombre) VALUES (:id_tipotienda,:tienda_nombre)');     
    $consulta->bindParam(':tienda_nombre',  $this->tienda_nombre);        
    $consulta->execute();
    $this->id= $conexion->lastInsertId();        

}
```

En la misma clase pretendo usar otro método que recoja la última ID insertada resultante del *lastInsertId*

```
//**
// SELECT 

public function selecT(){
    $conexion = new conexion();
    $consulta = $conexion->prepare("SELECT * FROM " . self::TABLA ." where id_tienda = :id_tienda");
    $consulta->execute(array(':id_tienda' => LAST_INSERT_ID));
    $registro = $consulta->fetch();       
    if($registro){
        return new self($registro['tienda_nombre'],$id_tienda);
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Que luego recogeré con otra llamada desde otro fichero. 
Necesito saber cómo pasar esa id de un método al otro

EDIT: Añado la clase completa

```
            class Tienda {

                private $id_tienda;
                const TABLA = 'generica_tienda'; 

                public function getId(){
                    return $this->id_tienda;
                }
                public function getNombre(){
                    return $this->tienda_nombre;
                }   
                public function setId(){
                    $this->id_tienda = $id_tienda;
                }
                public function setNombre(){
                    $this->tienda_nombre = $tienda_nombre;
                }

                public function __construct($tienda_nombre,$id_tienda=null)
                {
                    $this->id_tienda = $id_tienda;
                    $this->tienda_nombre = $tienda_nombre;
                }

                public function inserT(){       
                    $conexion = new Conexion();
                    $conexion->exec("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
                    $consulta = $conexion->prepare('INSERT INTO '.self::TABLA.' (tienda_nombre) VALUES (:tienda_nombre)');     
                    $consulta->bindParam(':tienda_nombre',  $this->tienda_nombre);        
                    $consulta->execute();
                    $id_tienda= $conexion->lastInsertId();        
                }

                public static function selecT(){       
                    $conexion = new conexion();
                    $conexion->exec("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
                    $consulta = $conexion->prepare("SELECT * FROM " . self::TABLA . " WHERE id_tienda = :id_tienda ");
                    $consulta->execute(array(':id_tienda' => $id_tienda));
                    $registro = $consulta->fetch();
                    if($registro){
                        return new self($registro['tienda_nombre'], $id_tienda);
                    } else {
                        return false;
                    }
                }       
            }
```

Comment: Quizás no he entendido bien, pero parece que estás guardando el último id insertado en la propiedad `id`. ¿No puedes usar `$this->id` directamente?

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro Sí. Sin embargo, ignoro si ello me ayudaría a pasar esa ID a la segunda funcion.

Comment: Las dos funciones están dentro de una misma clase, y esa clase tiene una propiedad llamada `id` que se actualiza con cada `inserT`. En teoría, cuando llames al método `selecT`, si lees la propiedad `id` (`$this->id`) debería devolverte la última que se realizó (si se llamó a `inserT` antes). Quizás sería mejor si añadieses algo más de código (no todo) con la definición de la clase y la propiedad `id` además de los dos métodos en cuestión.

Comment: Y prueba a reemplazar `LAST_INSERT_ID` con `$this->id` en `selecT` y comprueba si eso funciona.

Comment: Ok, @AlvaroMontoro añado la clase, quizá ahí se pueda ver mejor